# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy' (Error happend in PyCharm)

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm, environment-variables

I just create a new project in PyCharm, then try to run the command scrapy startproject filename. Then the error happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\users\管理员\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in
 _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,

File "c:\users\管理员\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in
_run_code
exec(code, run_globals)

File "C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__m
ain__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'
```

Before I created this project, I had found that the administrator name was in Simple Chinese. To avoid the further problem in other project, I modify the name from simply Chinese as well and the file name in `C://users/管理员` (where I installed the Python) and in the Path in system environment variables.

Does this error happen because of modification of the name? Or is there any other default configuration in PyCharm I need to modify?

Comment: some good practice: avoid using utf-8 characters during coding, or you need to explicitly specify it on top of the file, also please make sure your pycharm is using same python executable to which you installed scrapy!

Comment: Hi Gahan, thanks for your suggestion. I think your comment is useful for me.Now I find the problem and solve it. I am trying to learn how to use the scrapy. But after installing the scrapy, I found the scrapy commands can only work in CMD interface(MS-DOC). If I type the same command in PyCharm, the error will happen.  I think there will be some  problem in the path of the file because I use the UTF-8 characters. So first I modify the Path environmental variables of Users from UTF-8(the Chinese one) to ANSI(the English one), then deleted all the previous Path environmental variables of system.

Comment: Then I modify the path setting in pip.exe, pip3.exe, scrapy.exe in  file //Python38/scripts from UTF-8(the Chinese one) to ANSI(the English characters). After that I try scrapy startproject projectname in Pycharm terminal interface, the command works. But I think there will be some other problems in my other previous installed documents. If needed, I will reinstall python38.

Answer (score 0):

After searching from a website named CSDN, I found this method works for my problem. I just briefly describe how I handle that.Hope it will be helpful for other people who meet the similar problem.
The link: https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_39278265/article/details/82938270

I installed the scrapy under C://user/管理员/.../Python38/...
And yesterday after I installed scrapy, I found it doesn't work in Pycharm but, in MS-DOS, it worked. Some people told me the path with UTF-8 characters caused the problem. So I modified the path from UTF-8 characters to English characters.

Then I deleted all the path environmental variables of Python in System and modified the path environmental variables of Python in Users from UTF-8 characters to English Characters.

After that I opened the pip.exe, pip3.exe, scrapy.exe in ...python38/scripts/ by Notepad and modified the path in the same way I did above.

After that I opened the PyCharm then run the command scrapy startproject projectname,it worked as in CMD interface and showed:

**You can start your first spider with:
cd sxh01
scrapy genspider example example.com**